# there are a file visible by terminal but not in file structure in visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I made a service in earlier in my angular project by using follow command.

```
ng g s core/auth
```

and I had wanted to make a module also in the same folder in above mentioned. then I used this command

```
ng g m core/auth
```

but the case is, I can not see the above mentioned modules in the file structure. as this(but services are can see),

[image]

and I used the internal terminal in the visual studio code. after using the "ls" command I saw the relevant files as follow.

[image]

then what should I do for this problem.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the explorer using refresh icon manually?

Comment: yes I did. but not got any favorable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So they are existing but not shown in Visual Studio Code, right?
That happens to me too and I can fix it with either restart Visual Studio Code or reopen the project.

Maybe there is a better solution, but this is easy and fast.

Comment: Worst case you can try STRG + O open file. Once I had to do that and after I opened it, it was shown in my project folder.